# How to display whole content of a html file inside a function of a PHP file

Tags: php, html

I want to plot a flot graph inside a PHP file

lets say I have a 'graph.html' file which is displaying properly in html format which contains jQuery , css etc.

my requirement is I need to call this file inside a function of a php file and that function when it returns it should display the graph in body part.

`

```
    function display_graph()
    {
     $out = '';   
     //some php stups..

     //here need to call the graph.html file`enter code here`

     $out .= 'graph.html';  // is there a way to do like this .
     return $out; 

    }

  ?>    `
```

I tried this way but didn't work

`

```
  include_once 'path/graph.html';

 function display_graph()
 { 
   $out = '';   
   //some php stups

   return $out ;

 } 
?>    
`
```

it print the graph but the graph plot on the header part not in body part

Any idea will be great help for me.
Thank you.

Comment: Try `$content = include '/path/to/file'; $out .= $content`

Comment: That looks like terrible application design. Maybe, you are looking for something like `file_get_contents`?

Comment: ah yeah thats what i meant, `file_get_contents` if its a plain non php file

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php